# How to solve undefined migration files error in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have created some migration files in laravel 5.3. Then I did migration command. After that I added some columns to my table in one theese migration files and then I deleted one migration files...then I run php artisan migrate:refresh and then I got this error :
[image]
This error is coming from the migration file that I deleted. It seems that migrate:refresh still needs it. So How do I solve this error...?

Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had trouble with this too initially, but realized it was how I was implementing my CLI (command line interface) migration commands. Please read below.

When you create a migration file and then run php artisan migrate a few things happen on a fresh empty database:

1. A migration table is created to store and keep track of the migrations you have in your DB **AND** in your migration file directory.
2. The migration file's "UP" method is fired and any logic within the method is processed. Which in most cases, will typically use the Schema class to store a table in the database.

=========================================================================

Now, when you run the 'php artisan migrate:refresh' command, some things happen.

1. The system checks the database's tables based on what's stored inside of the migrations table to see if the table(s) exist.
2. It will thoroughly comb the database and empty ALL tables of all data.
3. Then it will use the information stored in the migrations table to check what the "down" method of each table's migration class has coded that may need to be processed.
4. In most cases it will typically fire a "dropIfExists" method within the "down" method of that specific class belonging to that table listed in the migrations table.

   **Here's where your error occured**

If the migrations table had a migration class listed in it and the system checks to see if that class exists within the database/migration directory and it's not there? You will normally get some kind of error that references that missing table in one way or another. It depends on how interconnected that table is to everything else or if that table is even listed in the migrations table at all.

The way to resolve this issue is to make sure the way you update your database makes sense.

**If permanently deleting migration files**

Clear the database and the migration table

1. **BEFORE** deleting any migration files, perform 'php aritsan migrate:rollback'
2. Delete the migration file.
3. Perform 'php artisan migrate' or 'migrate:refresh' (if you really want to)

**If updating a database table**

1. **After** updating the migration file, perform 'php artisan migrate' to add the migration in a new batch or 'or 'migrate:refresh' to keep the update within the same migration batch.

Comment: Cool... Thanks... :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating that file manually... :v
May be there is good way for solving this problem... :)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the db and create it again.

Then run  this command in the command line

`composer dump-autoload`

Then run this command

```
php artisan migrate
```